# CalendarExtender with two digit year

Tags: asp.net

There is a demand that user can input date in textbox or select a date with calendar. I use a textbox in which user input date, and a rangevalidator(type is date) to validate user's input, and calendar extender as calendar, and a button to popup the calendar. When user input the two digit year (like 9/24/11), the rangvalidator think is a valid date, but when I click button, the calendar extender display today. How can I let calendar extender jump to correct  date(9/24/2011)?

Here is the code:

```
<div style="display:inline-table">
    <div style="vertical-align:middle">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime" runat="server" CssClass="calInput" MaxLength="10" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnShowCalendar" runat="server" 
            CssClass="calInput calImg" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.gif" 
            onclick="imgBtnShowCalendar_Click" />
    </div>
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Animated="false" Format="MM/dd/yyyy"  TargetControlID="txtDateTime" PopupButtonID="imgBtnShowCalendar">
    </cc1:CalendarExtender>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="txtDateTime" Display="Dynamic" 
        ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" 
        ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1"  MinimumValue="1/1/1900" 
        MaximumValue="6/6/2079" Type="Date" ControlToValidate="txtDateTime" 
        runat="server" ErrorMessage="RangeValidator" Display="Dynamic" 
        Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RangeValidator>
</div>
```

Comment: I have not used CalendarExtender, so just giving some idea.

there is a Format property, try set to 
Format="M/dd/yy"

Comment: I change to Format = "M/dd/yy", but when user input the 4 digit year, the calendarExtender can't recognize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from http://forums.asp.net/t/1391032.aspx is to add client-side function to fix this problem. You should add `MaskedEditExtender` with `MaskedEditValidator` and set `ClientValidationFunction`. Also you may need to set `ClientIDMode` property of your `txtDateTime` fileld to `Static`.

```
<div style="display:inline-table">

    <%-- ... --%>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="calInput" MaxLength="10" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>

    <%-- ... --%>

    <%-- all yours previous code goes here --%>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function FixCentury(sender, args) {
            // the current value is saved as args.Value;
            // you can modify the method of changing the value yourself.
            var year = args.Value.split("/")[2];
            if (year.substr(0, 2) == "00") {
                var newyear = "20" + year.substr(2, 2);
                document.getElementById("txtDateTime").value = args.Value.substr(0, 6) + newyear;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDateTime"
        MaskType="Date" Mask="99/99/9999" Century="2100" AutoComplete="true">
    </cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
    <cc1:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator1" runat="server" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender1"
        ControlToValidate="txtDateTime" IsValidEmpty="false" InvalidValueMessage="Check date!"
        InvalidValueBlurredMessage="Check date!" Display="Dynamic" ClientValidationFunction="FixCentury" />
</div>
```